# Build project multiple times

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a project (a WP7 app), lets call it "Restaurants".

Now, instead of having one app with a list of the restaurants, I want to have an app per restaurant.

Each of these apps will be synced with WCF service. The app can ask for new data, download menus etc...

But the requirement is, that the apps must not be empty when first run on target device (there must be some data, like location etc.)

Here is how I imagine it would work - using MSBuild, it would download a list of all restaurants from the service and then for each of them (in a cycle) it would download the interesting data, feeding it into the application (say in a form of an XML file). Along with the XML file for each app, the build target would need to be different (name of the restaurant).

Can this be done in MSBuild? I have never worked with it before, so I will be glad for any pointers